# После printf и FreeConsole программа ждет

Tags: c++, windows, printf

Вот функция:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
if (!AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
    MessageBox(NULL, L"The console window was not created", NULL, 
    MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

  FILE* fp;
  freopen_s(&fp, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
  printf("Hello\n");
  fclose(fp);

if (!FreeConsole())
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to free the console!", NULL, 
    MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
  return 0;
}
```

Но при запуски ее из `cmd` `Program.exe` после `Hello` и нет новой строки command line, а просто пустая, в которую можно ввести любую команду.
Пример:

```
C:/>hello.exe
Hello
|
```

(последний знак это как будто курсор)

Пробовал `AllocConsole()` но открывается новая консоль, а надо писать в эту. `FreeConsole()` отрабатывает, но все равно после `Hello` ожидание чего то.

Comment: Попробуйте `"Hello\r\n"`

Comment: это особенность консоли windows, для перехода нужно два символа. 10 потом 13. или `\r\n`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13295575/5727271

Comment: Вот хороший ответ из сети https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n

Comment: Почему **maint**? это вся программа, или есть ещё код, который может вызвать "ожидание"?

Comment: ошибся в когда вопрос писал. (Вместо main maint)

Comment: @nick_n_a - вообще то \n хорошо конвертируется.  Нужно чуточку больше информации - компилятор, список include вверху (может там define на printf)

Comment: отредактировал, как это сейчас работает, видимо ошибка не в \r\n а в освобождении консоли. FreeConsole() отрабатывает, но все равно ошибка остается